# select all the rows from data frame including recurring rows based on vector R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to bootstrap a data set according to a vector of years:

this is my datasframe df:

```
'data.frame':   103 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ date     : Date, format: "1962-08-01" "1982-08-01" "1983-08-01" ...
 $ flow     : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.404 ...
 $ hydroYear: Factor w/ 45 levels "1950","1951",..: 11 27 28 29 33 35 36 37 40 41 ...
```

I'm using boot like this:

```
qmat <- boot(data=as.integer(as.vector(unique(df$hydroYear))),statstic=xboot,R=100)
```

now I want to create a new dataframe out of df where all the rows that have the same `df$hydro` year as the boot year vector will be there, including repetition.

So for example if me data frame is:

```
flow    hydroYear
1       1951
2       1951
3       1953
4       1954
5       1954
6       1956
```

and the bootstrap vector is:

```
1954 1953 1954 1951
```

I will get a dataframe that looks like this:

```
flow    hydroYear
4       1954
5       1954
3       1953
4       1954
5       1954
1       1951
2       1951
```

I've tried this:

```
  xboot <-  function(yearboot,b,method){
    tmpyr <- yearboot[b]
    df1 <- df[df$hydroYear %in% tmpyr ,]}
```

but it doesn't create the recurring rates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the only way to do it, but

```
mydf <- data.frame(flow=c(1,2,3,4,5,6), hydroYear=c(1951,1951,1953,1954,1954,1956))
boot <- c(1954,1953,1954,1951)
do.call(rbind, lapply(boot, FUN=function(x){mydf[mydf$hydroYear == x, ]}))
```

gives

```
   flow hydroYear
4     4      1954
5     5      1954
3     3      1953
41    4      1954
51    5      1954
1     1      1951
2     2      1951
```

Comment: Also, `df[unlist(sapply(boot, function(x) which(df$hydroYear %in% x))), ]  `

Comment: @RonakShah I used your answer. It was easier for me to understand. Thanks.